# Ubuntu stalls at boot-up

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

I appreciate anyone's help in advance. This is driving me crazy.

I am going to explain all I have done so that I hope it helps in figuring this out.

1. I installed 18.04 on a 2007 MacBook Pro. Didn't notice any errors. I installed using a USB made from a Windows machine and formatted the drive.
2. On restart, I noticed that the graphics seemed off at first but then recovered when the logo appeared.
3. During the boot-up, the system stalls. I restarted multiple times and the system stalls at various points. I don't see anything consistent.
4. I researched this and found many users with the same problem and I followed mostly all the advice given.
5. Someone suggested that because I didn't unmount my USB, it could be a problem. So I followed the instructions but instead of seeing the USB, I saw 2 instances of MacOS and one of them was in the boot sequence. I deleted all instances of the MacOS but the problem continued.
6. Lastly, I found a solution that stated that the partition might be too small and its running out of space. So I deleted all the partitions, made an EFI partition of 256mb and a root partition (about 250gb) and reinstalled. I encountered the same problem. This time though, I did notice some errors and I am writing what came up as I am not allowed to post pictures yet:

After installation:

- [ 10.475782] Couldn't get size: 0x80000000000000e
- [ 10.475830] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
- [ 10.512237] Couldn't get size: 0x80000000000000e
- [ 10.548659] Couldn't get size: 0x80000000000000e
- [ 11.101311] NOUVEAU 0000:04:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000807f FAULT at 100c18
- [ 11.184522] NOUVEAU 0000:04:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000807e FAULT at 100c1c

During Boot:

- [ OK ] Started Login Service
- [ OK ] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
- [ 68.760956] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: fb: trapped read at 01004b8000 on channel -1 [0fedf000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ]
  subclient 01 [IN] reason 0000000b [VRAM_LIMIT]

I rebooted again and it just stalled (HOLD) after Accounts Services, without any error messages.

Thanks,
Hector